# GridSearchCV() to fine tune outputs ValueError and FitFailedWarning

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm

I would like to fine tune some parameters for my linear SVM.

This is the code:

```
class SVMSentiment(Base):
"""Predict sentiment scores using a linear Support Vector Machine (SVM).
Uses a sklearn pipeline.
"""
def __init__(self, model_file: str=None) -> None:
    super().__init__()
    # pip install sklearn
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer, TfidfVectorizer
    from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
    from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
    self.pipeline = Pipeline(
        [
            #('vect', CountVectorizer()),
            #('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
            ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
            ('clf', LinearSVC(



            #('clf', SGDClassifier(
              #  loss='hinge',
               # penalty='l2',
                #alpha=1e-4,
                #random_state=42,
                #max_iter=100,
                #learning_rate='optimal',
                #tol=None,

            )),
        ]
    )

def predict(self, train_file: str, test_file: str, lower_case: bool) -> pd.DataFrame:
    "Train model using sklearn pipeline"
    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    train_df = self.read_data(train_file, lower_case)
    parameters = {'C': [1, 10],
                  'gamma': [0.001, 0.01, 1]}
    model = SVC()
    grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=parameters)
    grid.fit(train_df['text'], train_df['truth'])
    print(grid)
    # summarize the results of the grid search
    print(grid.best_params_)
    print(grid.best_estimator_)

    learner = self.pipeline.fit(train_df['text'], train_df['truth'])
    # Fit the learner to the test data
    test_df = self.read_data(test_file, lower_case)

    test_df['pred'] = learner.predict(test_df['text'])
    return test_df
```

However, I am having some issues as it raised some ValueErrors:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

and I do not know how to deal with this information. And also:

```
FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition 
for these parameters will be set to nan
```

How can I solve these?

Comment: In your grid search you don't tfidf-encode, so the SVC model is getting the raw strings.

Comment: and the FitFailedWarning is just letting you know that in a grid search, errors in fitting get ignored so that you can fit the other hyperparameter points (though in this case all of them will fail)

Comment: thank you, and how I should tfidf encode?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the data `train_df` or `test_df` where ever the error is coming has a column which has a `string(object)` data type. You cannot fit `string` data into a model. Only numerical data is allowed.

1. Try printing:

   ```
   print(train_df.info())
   print(test_df.info())
   ```

to see which column should be `float` type but is a string.

Comment: Here is the answer: <class 'classifiers.SVMSentiment'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 8544 entries, 0 to 8543
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   truth   8544 non-null   category
 1   text    8544 non-null   object
dtypes: category(1), object(1)